# How do you get "Slashing Sword "Farewell"" in Valkyrie Profile 2?

Tags: valkyrie-profile-2

I recently read of a light warrior sword called "Slashing Sword "Farewell"". I am aware that other weapons are obtained when certain characters leave your party at certain levels in certain chapters, but I’m having trouble finding this one.

How can I can obtain "Slashing Sword "Farewell""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Valkyria Profile Wiki](http://valkyrieprofile.wikia.com/wiki/Valkyrie_Profile_Wiki) on Wikia states that [the sword](http://valkyrieprofile.wikia.com/wiki/Slashing_Sword_%22Farewell%22) is obtained at the end of Chapter 3 when Leone leaves the party. [Leones](http://valkyrieprofile.wikia.com/wiki/Leone) page (under bonus items) states that she must be between level 35-40+ for [the sword](http://valkyrieprofile.wikia.com/wiki/Slashing_Sword_%22Farewell%22) to appear, while the page for [the sword](http://valkyrieprofile.wikia.com/wiki/Slashing_Sword_%22Farewell%22) simply states level 40+.